# bridge substrate solo chain to parachain

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, substrate-contracts-node

I am trying to bridge a solo substrate chain to a parachain .
I am very new to this.
I came across the parity-bridges-common repo (https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common) . I was able to run it using the instructions.

1. How do I use thesame repo to bridge a solo-chain and a parachain since the example chains used i.e millau and rialto are solochains
2. why are their two rialto chains in
3. bin/rialto
4. bin/rialto-parachain
5. what modifications do I have to make to the code to bridge my own chains rather than milla and rialto
6. is there any detailed documentation or support to accomplish this

Comment: Rialto is a Relay chain and you need to add modules in your both chains and make them available in your runtime too. Then make the relay(the middle service) compatiable to both chains.

Comment: @Arunjot Singh so Rialto is a relay chain and Rialto-parachain is a parachain connected to Rialto relay ? Is there any instruction on how to go about adding the modules ?

Comment: @Arunjot Singh. This high level architecture shows that both Rialto and Millau are solo chains and neither is relay chain https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common

Comment: The high level architecture documentation is not updated. Earlier both were solo-chains but now Rialto is a relay chain.

Comment: You need add bridges modules(pallets) in your chain, and make them compatiable to your chain. The only issue is going to come in your way is dependency issue. Otherwise it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

[A prototype to show bridge between a solo-chain and a parachain based on Parity Substrate <> Substrate bridge.](https://github.com/paritytech/solo-para-bridge-poc)

Comment: I tried to build this project but I am getting errors and some dependencies git-repos have been deleted